# Extract parameters from Exiftool to haskell

Tags: haskell, exiftool

I'm writing a program in Haskell that needs the metadata from media files, such as runtime, artist, size, name, copyright, height....

Basically I need to get this information and create some pdf's with it, but I can't find a way to get the values like "60s", "AC/DC", "5000", "Thunderstruck", "copyright"...

Any ideas hot to parse info that `exiftool` gives? Which parameters in `exiftool` are better to use? Should I use `Text.Regex`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Example of how to parse exiftool JSON output in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089194/example-of-how-to-parse-exiftool-json-output-in-haskell)

Answer (score 2):

Since `exiftool` can produce XML or JSON output, you can pick one format and parse the output accordingly. Haskell has [Text.XML.Light](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml) (and bunch of others) for parsing XML and [aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson) for JSON.

As for what tags available in EXIF, take a look at [this convenient list](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html).