# How to parse uncertain data from JSON in Haskell?

Tags: json, parsing, haskell

I used the answer in [json_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089194/example-of-how-to-parse-exiftool-json-output-in-haskell?answertab=active#tab-top) (Text.JSON package) and I've got a generic json Haskell data type. It's ok to define a custom Haskell data type for certain data, but if the data I want to parse is uncertain,

For example, if I got a response A from some APIs, the field is "category" this time:

```
[JSObject (JSONObject {fromJSObject = [("category",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "photo"}))]})]
```

And next time, "address":

```
[JSObject (JSONObject {fromJSObject = [("address",JSString (JSONString {fromJSString = "http://www.example.com"}))]})]
```

or some other uncertain fields, and the generic json type may be nested.

how can I extract it from the json data type?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that `Data.Aeson` is probably the more-standard Haskell JSON lib: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson

Comment: @amindfv Aeson is a good lib for doing this, and I have used it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `Data.Aeson` library and it solved my question.

`decode` in `Data.Aeson` can produce a `Maybe Value` result. And I used pattern matching to extract the values from the `Maybe Value` result like follow:

```
json2Array :: Maybe Value -> Array
json2Array (Just (Array anArray)) = anArray

arrayValue2Object :: Value -> Object
arrayValue2Object (Object anObject) = anObject
```

And in Data.Aeson, `Object` constructor is a synonym of `HashMap Text Value` so I can use the
Data.HashMap.Lazy/Strict to extract the values I need.

This method may not good, but it realy helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the documentation for [`Text.JSON`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/json/latest/doc/html/Text-JSON.html), something like this might work for you:

```
import Text.JSON

data Foo = Category String
         | Address String
         deriving (Show)

toJSO = JSObject . toJSObject

instance JSON Foo where
    showJSON (Category s) = toJSO [("category", showJSON s)]
    showJSON (Address s)  = toJSO [("address",  showJSON s)]
    readJSON (JSObject obj) = case o of
      [("category", JSString s)] -> Ok $ Category $ fromJSString s
      [("address",  JSString s)] -> Ok $ Address  $ fromJSString s
      where
        o = fromJSObject obj
```

Basically this says:  if the JSON object has just a "category" field then it's a Category, and same for "address".  To really make this work you'd add another clause to the case and the readJSON for indicating a "parse" error.

Then to parse your example, you'd do:

```
decode "some-JSON-here" :: Result [Foo]
```

which magically works because of this instance:

```
JSON a => JSON [a]
```

There are probably better ways of doing this, but this worked for me and seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: For completeness/total-ness, there should be a `_ -> Error "Unrecognised Foo"` pattern in the `case`.

Comment: It's great to define certain field like you do, but if there are lots of uncertain fields? The fields may __vary every time__ when I received responses from some API, and I can't even be sure what the fields are.